# Real and imaginary parts of complex logarithm

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, complex

I need to obtain the real and imaginary parts of the below expression with Mathematica:

$(- i a - m^2) \ln(\frac{i m^2}{2 a})$,

where $a$ and $m$ are real.

So we have:

```
Refine[Re[(-I a - m^2) Log[(I m^2)/(2 a)]], {Element[a, Reals], Element[m, Reals]}]
```

However, Mathematica returns the command again. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand) and then [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify):

```
Simplify[ComplexExpand[ReIm[(-I a - m^2) Log[(I m^2)/(2 a)]]], a > 0]
Simplify[ComplexExpand[ReIm[(-I a - m^2) Log[(I m^2)/(2 a)]]], a < 0]
```

> {(a π)/2 - m^2 Log[1/(2 a)] - m^2 Log[m^2], -((m^2 π)/2) - 
>     a Log[1/(2 a)] - a Log[m^2]}
>
> {-((a π)/2) - m^2 Log[-(1/(2 a))] - m^2 Log[m^2], (m^2 π)/2 - 
>     a Log[-(1/(2 a))] - a Log[m^2]}

An alternative, as Bob Hanlon mentions, is to use [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand) with the option `TargetFunctions->{Re, Im}`

Comment: Thanks. Why isn't any $a$ in your final solution?

Comment: @Carl appears to have set `a = 2`. For arbitrary `a` use `ComplexExpand[ReIm[(-I a - m^2) Log[(I m^2)/(2 a)]], 
 TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]`